# React Update Fetch on Checkbox Click

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have a component(Card) that has checkboxes that are tracked in a localhost database using Postgres.  When I check or uncheck the box, an entry gets put into the networkusers table.  The problem is that when I check or uncheck the box, and then click on a button to render a different component and then come back to the Card component with the checkboxes, the boxes are not showing the updated check.  However, if I sign out and sign back in, all the boxes are updated and in sync with database.  So how do I get the component to render (or fetch again?) as soon as checkbox is changed in the following component?  TY.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const onUpdateCB = (ischecked, loginuser, userid, setisChecked,handleCheck,event) => {

  console.log(ischecked, loginuser, userid);

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/cb', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body:JSON.stringify({
      loginuser,
      userid,
      ischecked: ischecked
    })
  }).then(setisChecked(ischecked)); 
};

const Card = props => {
  const [isChecked, setisChecked] = useState(props.ischecked);
  return (
    <div
      className="pointer bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 shadow-5"
      onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.id)}
      //onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}

    >
      <div>
        <h3>{props.name}</h3>
        <p>{props.company}</p>
        <p>{props.phone}</p>
        <p>{props.email}</p>
        <p>{props.city}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        My Network
        <input
          className="largeCheckbox"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          onClick={(event) =>
            onUpdateCB(!isChecked, props.loginuser.id, props.id, setisChecked,event.stopPropagation())
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Network Array

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

const NetworkArray = ({
  network,
  networkusers,
  handleChange,
  handleClick,
  loginuser
}) => {
  console.log("in network array", networkusers);

  const cardComponent = network.map((user, i) => {
    const ischecked = networkusers.filter(n => {
      var nw = n.id === loginuser.id && n.connections === network[i].id;
      return nw;
    });



    console.log("i'm checked", ischecked);

    return (

      <Card
        key={network[i].id}
        name={network[i].firstname + " " + network[i].lastname}
        company={network[i].company}
        phone={network[i].phone}
        email={network[i].email}
        city={network[i].city}
        ischecked={ischecked.length}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleClick={handleClick}
        id={network[i].id}
        loginuser={loginuser}
      />
    );
  });
  return <div>{cardComponent}</div>;
};

export default NetworkArray;
```

Comment: The Card property `ischecked={ischecked.length}` looks suspicious - you probably want `ischecked = networkusers.some(n => n.id === loginuser.id && n.connections === network[i].id);` and set the property with ` `ischecked={ischecked}`.

Comment: I changed it to your suggestion and still get the same result.  When I click on another button to render another component and then come back to the component with checkboxes, the checkboxes still are not updated.  I only see the changes when I sign out and sign back in.  Any idea?

Comment: I saw another question where the solution was to use the ***function updater form*** of the useState setter, see the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). So the change in `onUpdateCB` would be `}).then(setisChecked(previousValue => !previousValue))`. The problem in the other question was one of timing, which may also be your problem since a fetch occurs before the setter is called. Also, try calling the setter before the fetch, which will give you the "standard" pattern of update.

Comment: See another pattern here [Custom setters with React useState hook](https://gustavostraube.wordpress.com/2019/05/29/custom-setters-with-react-usestate-hook/), your fetch would occur where he says `// Some side-effect here ...`. I would make the custom setter an `async` function and `await` the fetch.

Comment: Tried this but getting same result:
const onUpdateCB = (ischecked, loginuser, userid, setisChecked,event) => {

  console.log(ischecked, loginuser, userid);
  setisChecked(previousValue => !previousValue)

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/cb', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body:JSON.stringify({
      loginuser,
      userid,
      ischecked: ischecked
    })
  })
};

Comment: Can you show how you would modify the existing code in original post?

Comment: The change you made looks correct, so I'd need to get your code running to figure out what to do. Do you have a repository, by chance? Or a sandbox or fiddle?

Comment: Richard,  Here are the files.  Thanks much for looking at this.  
https://github.com/brianlbradley/networkappbackend
https://github.com/brianlbradley/networkappfrontend-master

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there are two principal you have to follow in React Application.

**1. Don't store two source of truth in any of application state.** 
At the moment, the Card store its own state `isChecked`, and also somewhere above `Network` has fetch value from database and has `isChecked` passed down to Card component too.

Having multiple source of truth is not good, and will usually come back to haunt us later, so rule no 1., **Do not have multiple source of truth**

`Fix #1: remove "isChecked" state from Card.`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const onUpdateCB = (ischecked, loginuser, userid) => {

  console.log(ischecked, loginuser, userid);

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/cb', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body:JSON.stringify({
      loginuser,
      userid,
      ischecked: ischecked
    })
  }); 
};

const Card = props => {
  const { ischecked } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className="pointer bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 shadow-5"
      onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.id)}
      //onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
    >
      <div>
        <h3>{props.name}</h3>
        <p>{props.company}</p>
        <p>{props.phone}</p>
        <p>{props.email}</p>
        <p>{props.city}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        My Network
        <input
          className="largeCheckbox"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={ischecked}
          onClick={(event) =>
            onUpdateCB(!isChecked, props.loginuser.id, props.id)
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

.... actually the first principal should be enough to fix your case. But in case you're curious.

**2. Do side-effect on after render (componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, useEffect).**

A flow should be like this, 
`event => setState => render => side-effect`

1. User interact with something (click, press, touch, focus, etc.)
2. You set new value to a state (or pass props, to set parent's state... same same)
3. You render the change
4. in after render lifecycle/hook, you perform side-effect (eg. api call)

Let assume your card component is stand alone, does not receive value from props.

```
const onUpdateCB = (ischecked, loginuser, userid) => {
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/cb', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body:JSON.stringify({
      loginuser,
      userid,
      ischecked: ischecked
    })
  }); 
}

const Card = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  // 2: set new state
  const onSelectCheckbox = (ischecked) => {
    const newData = { ...data, ischecked };
    setData(newData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // 4. Watch if data.ischecked change, if yes perform side effect (call api)
    onUpdateCB(data.ischecked, props.loginuser.id, props.id);
  }, [data.ischecked]);

  // 3. re-render when data change.
  const { name, company, phone, email, city, ischecked } = data;
  return (
    <div className="pointer bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 shadow-5">
      <div>
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <p>{company}</p>
        <p>{phone}</p>
        <p>{email}</p>
        <p>{city}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        My Network
        <input
          className="largeCheckbox"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={ischecked}
          onClick={(event) =>
            onSelectCheckbox(!isChecked) // 1. User interact with checkbox
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  When I  use the first option, the checkboxes are disabled and want allow me to check or uncheck.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the problem is in `Card`'s parent. It passes initial value for checked state (`props.ischecked`), so you probably need to notify it about state change and make your `Card` fully-controlled without it's own state.

There are several options how to do that, depends of state management strategy you use.

1. If you just hold this state in some parent component:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [ ischecked, setChecked ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Card ischecked={ ischecked } ... />
  );
}
```

In this case provide callback for changing state to `Card` component:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Card ischecked={ ischecked } onCheckedChange={ setChecked } ... />
  );
}

...

const Card = (props) => {
  ...

    return (
    <div ...>
        ...
        <input
          ...
          checked={props.ischecked}
          onClick={(event) =>
            onUpdateCB(!isChecked, props.loginuser.id, props.id, props.onCheckedChange,event.stopPropagation())
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. If you use Redux for managing state - move checkbox state to redux:

```js
import { setChecked } from './actions';

const Card = props => {
  // the same as above
}

export default connect(state => ({
  ischecked: state.ischecked
}), {
  onCheckedChange: setChecked
})(Card);
```

P.S. Also you have a typo in you `onUpdateCB()` method - you should use a function as a promise callback:

```js
 }).then(
  () => setisChecked(ischecked)
);
```

Currently you just set checked state at the same moment.

Comment: Andres, Can you show me how to update this in the parent NetworkArray component?  I added that component to the question.

Comment: Can this be implemented with the two components that I listed above, or do I need another component?  The only other component that relates to this is the App.js component.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify it carefully.

The first render.

1. The prop named ischecked of Card was given by the parent component: NetworkArray. Let's say it was **false** at that moment.
2. In the child component Card, it initialized a local state named isChecked which the initial value is the same with prop ischecked(false), and wrapper a bit of logic to update the state by user actions and API response. After a bunch of user actions, let's say it was changed to be **true** eventually. In the code only the local state updated but the prop in parent stayed the same.

The second render.
Then the second time the same Card was rendered, again the prop **ischecked** is false, in the Card, it was unchecked since the computed local state isChecked was false.

So we see the reason why the Card didn't show the updated **isChecked** because that the prop **ischecked** not changed.

The method to fix this issue is to ensure the prop **ischecked** being updated successfully, not only the local state.  I'm not sure how to make this work in your code because the **ischecked** is computed by lots of other props, try to make it yourself and good luck.

Finally, why the issue didn't occur after sign out and sign in? Because in this way the props in the parent were fully reloaded with the updated data including **ischecked** related pieces. So you got the updated value of the checkbox. That's it.

Comment: Is there any way you could look at the code?  I've tried so many iterations of this and nothing has worked.  I feel this is beyond my comprehension at this point, but i do appreciate the theory!   github.com/brianlbradley/networkappbackend github.com/brianlbradley/networkappfrontend-master

Comment: @Ginger22 I would recommend to re-fetch the related data if an update from Card successfully. And derive ischecked prop based on the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

In React, when a component is unmounted, it looses its internal state.

So when you come back to it, you must make sur that the `props.ischecked` from the Card has the updated value, which comes from above with `network` prop of NetworkArray.

So you need to make sure that that `network` prop is different once that `fetch` has been done when you come back to that component.

Typically, above NetworkArray, you would have a fetch in ComponentDidMount that updates the network prop.

Here is how the whole code may look like :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";


class ComponentAboveNetworkArray extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       /* ... */
       network: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     fetch('http://localhost:3000/cb')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(json => this.setState({network: json.network}))
  }

  return (
    <NetworkArray /* ... */ network={this.state.network} />
  )
}


const NetworkArray = ({
  network,
  networkusers,
  handleChange,
  handleClick,
  loginuser
}) => {
  console.log("in network array", networkusers);

  const cardComponent = network.map((user, i) => {
      const ischecked = networkusers.some(n => {
         var nw = n.id === loginuser.id && n.connections === network[i].id;
         return nw;
      });

      console.log("i'm checked", ischecked);

      return (
         <Card
            key={network[i].id}
            name={network[i].firstname + " " + network[i].lastname}
            company={network[i].company}
            phone={network[i].phone}
            email={network[i].email}
            city={network[i].city}
            ischecked={ischecked}
            handleClick={handleClick}
            id={network[i].id}
            loginuser={loginuser}
         />
       );
     });
  return <div>{cardComponent}</div>;
};

export default NetworkArray;
```

Comment: Above Network Array?  Can you put this in the context of the code in original post?  I tried this and getting that Hooks can only be implemented within a function component.

Comment: I used a useEffect hook, but it can be done with a class Component as well, with ComponentDidMount.

Comment: I tried this in the NetworkArray component but still getting same results-if i check the checkbox and then come back to the component it shows unchecked.  I showed how I tried this as an addendum to your answer. Please take a look. Thx!

Comment: I made a codepen : https://codepen.io/exifers/pen/oNgxwjK?editors=1111 , I simplified a bit your code, I used a custom public API I made a while ago for storing todos.
As you can see, it fetches the data on each mount and populates the state so that it matches what's in the database.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This part is in the App.js, which i didn't include.  But i put this in the NetworkArray component and the App component.  
return (
    <NetworkArray /* ... */ network={this.state.network} />
  )
}
I put along with the other code and still getting same result.

Comment: Well if you still can't figure it out, I think you should make a codepen with your code. Maybe replace fetches with some delays that change a global object acting like the database. Then it would be easier to fix.